# --py-files in Spark Submit causing Module not found

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

We are passing few ZIP files to the `Spark-Submit` with the options `--py-files` a sample below.

```
spark-submit --master yarn \
--name Application \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--driver-memory 3g \
--py-files "/<PATH>/Specific_App.zip","/<PATH>/Utilities.zip"
```

While running the Spark Application, my understanding is the ZIP files are unzipped during the run time to access the Python files(modules).
Now I have few questions on this regard...

- Are the ZIP files unzipped and kept in **MEMORY**
- How can I get to know if the files are UNZIPPED properly within the Spark Application
- Does the UNZIPPING of files create a parent folder with the same name as the ZIP file
- Lets say in my scenario both my ZIP files have a common tree structure, for example (parent/child1/child2 dont have any files within them but just its child subdirectory)

`Utilities.zip -> parent/child1/child2/utilities/`

`Specific_App.zip -> parent/child1/child2/Specific_App/`

In this scenario while UNZIPPING the ZIP files would there be issues, as lets say Specific_App.zip gets unzipped the folder structure parent/child1/child2 would be already available if the Utilities.zip was unzipped prior.

I am getting a Module not found error, and see that the imported module is in the right path within the Utilities.zip.

Please do let me know if any more information is required.